# Hiding form data from the search bar

Tags: html

I'm pretty inexperienced with HTML, I'm creating a log in page and am wondering how to hide the form data from the URL.
Ex:
[www.example.com/?txt=username&pswd=password](http://www.example.com/?txt=username&pswd=password)

I've tried using type = hidden instead of password but that wasn't any use.

Answer (score 0):

Usually HTML forms that contain things like passwords use `method="POST"`. This will cause the form values to be submitted in a request body, instead of a URL.